# A question about 2-dimensional manifolds having constant negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

For each positive integer n, let E(n) be n-dimensional Euclide3an space. Let S be the surface of revolution obtained by rotating  a tracktrix about its asymptote. S is a so-called "pseudosphere", has a constant negative Gaussian curvature at each point and-as a metric space-S is congruent to a subset of E(3). However S is a 2-dimensional topological manifold with boundary. Does there exist a 2-dimensional metric space M which (1) is a topological manifold without boundary (2)has constant negative Gaussian curvature at each point and (3)is congruent- as a metric space-to a subset of E(n), for some positive integer n greater than 3? If so can M be compact?

Comment: Every Riemannian manifold can be embedded isometrically in some large Euclidean space; every surface can be embedded in, IIRC, $\Bbb R^{13}$ or something. So your (3) is automatically satisfied. For (1) and (2) + compact: every surface of genus $g \geq 2$ admits (many non-isometric) metrics of constant curvature $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem), any $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ admits an isometric (in the metric space sense) $C^1$ embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. If $M$ is compact, then it further admits an isometric (in the Riemannian sense) $C^{\infty}$ embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{\frac{m(3m+11)}{2}}$. So for $m = 2$ we get embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^{17}$ respectively.

So your question reduces to whether there exist closed [hyperbolic manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_manifold) of dimension $2$, and the answer is yes, in fact there are lots: any closed connected surface of genus $g \ge 2$ admits uncountably many nonisometric hyperbolic metrics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information . In defining M , I neglected  to specify that  M should be congruent to a closed connected subset  of  E(n). Without  this additional requirement , many proper subsets of  S would fulfill the other conditions I imposed on M.  S itself is, of course, ruled out-since it is a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @Garabed: if $M$ is compact and connected, its image under any embedding into $\mathbb{R}^n$ will automatically be closed and connected.

Comment: I added the extra condition to cover cases  where M is without boundary but not necessarily compact. I realize that connectedness is often-but not always-made part of the definition of a manifold.